# Wordpress error: Could not update post in the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hello Good Developers,

I am trying to update a post in wordpress but it is not allowing me to update the post.

I have tried - `wp_update_post` and `$wpdb->update` but both are not allowing me to update the post.

Here's the code that I used

```
   $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $found_post_id,
        'post_type'    => utf8_encode( $line_data['post_type'] ),
        'post_name'    => utf8_encode( $line_data['post_name'] ),
        'post_title'    => utf8_encode( $line_data['post_title'] ),
        'post_content'  => utf8_encode( 'tada' ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );
    $status = wp_update_post($my_post, true);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($status);

    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';

    $status = $wpdb->update( $table, $my_post, array( 'ID' => $found_post_id ));
    echo "<pre>";print_r($status);die;
```

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [db_update_error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Could not update post in the database
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I cloned the Database to a new one to check if its the issue with different charset but that as well didn't solve my problem.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.